# Convert HOCON string into Java object

Tags: java, json, parsing, pojo, hocon

One of my webservice return below Java string:

```
[
  {
    id=5d93532e77490b00013d8862, 
    app=null,
    manufacturer=pearsonEducation, 
    bookUid=bookIsbn, 
    model=2019,
    firmware=[1.0], 
    bookName=devotional, 
    accountLinking=mandatory
  }
]
```

I have the equivalent Java object for the above string. I would like to typecast or convert the above java string into Java Object.

I couldn't type-cast it since it's a String, not an object. So, I was trying to convert the Java string to JSON string then I can write that string into Java object but no luck getting **`invalid character "="`** exception.

> Can you change the web service to return JSON?

That's not possible. They are not changing their contracts. It would be super easy if they returned JSON.

Comment: They are not clear with the format so we may expect comma in the string. Do we have any other way?

Comment: @f1sh Actually, it is a standard format. It's called [HOCON](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md).

Answer (score 11):

The format your web-service returns has it's own name **HOCON**. (You can read more about it [here](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md))

You **do not need your custom parser**. Do not try to reinvent the wheel. 
Use an existing one instead.

---

Add this maven dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
    <artifactId>config</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then parse the response as follows:

```
Config config = ConfigFactory.parseString(text);

String id = config.getString("id");
Long model = config.getLong("model");
```

---

There is also an option to parse the whole string into a POJO:

```
MyResponsePojo response = ConfigBeanFactory.create(config, MyResponsePojo.class);
```

Unfortunately this parser does not allow `null` values. So you'll need to handle exceptions of type `com.typesafe.config.ConfigException.Null`.

---

Another option is to convert the `HOCON` string into `JSON`:

```
String hoconString = "...";
String jsonString = ConfigFactory.parseString(hoconString)
                                 .root()
                                 .render(ConfigRenderOptions.concise());
```

Then you can use any JSON-to-POJO mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is definitely not the best answer to be given here, but it is possible, at least…

Manipulate the `String` in small steps like this in order to get a `Map<String, String>` which can be processed. See this example, it's very basic:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "[\r\n" 
            + "  {\r\n"
            + "    id=5d93532e77490b00013d8862, \r\n"
            + "    app=null,\r\n"
            + "    manufacturer=pearsonEducation, \r\n"
            + "    bookUid=bookIsbn, \r\n"
            + "    model=2019,\r\n"
            + "    firmware=[1.0], \r\n"
            + "    bookName=devotional, \r\n"
            + "    accountLinking=mandatory\r\n"
            + "  }\r\n"
            + "]";

    // manipulate the String in order to have
    String[] splitData = data
            // no leading and trailing [ ] - cut the first and last char
            .substring(1, data.length() - 1)
            // no linebreaks
            .replace("\n", "")
            // no windows linebreaks
            .replace("\r", "")
            // no opening curly brackets
            .replace("{", "")
            // and no closing curly brackets.
            .replace("}", "")
            // Then split it by comma
            .split(",");

    // create a map to store the keys and values
    Map<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();

    // iterate the key-value pairs connected with '='
    for (String s : splitData) {
        // split them by the equality symbol
        String[] keyVal = s.trim().split("=");
        // then take the key
        String key = keyVal[0];
        // and the value
        String val = keyVal[1];
        // and store them in the map ——> could be done directly, of course
        dataMap.put(key, val);
    }

    // print the map content
    dataMap.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " ——> " + value));
}
```

> Please note that I just copied your example `String` which may have caused the line breaks and I think it is not smart to just `replace()` all square brackets because the value `firmware` seems to include those as content.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we split the parse process in two step.

1. Format the output data to JSON.
2. Parse text by JSON utils.

In this demo code, i choose regex as format method, and fastjson as JSON tool. you can choose jackson or gson. Furthermore, I remove the `[` `]`, you can put it back, then parse it into array.

```
import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SerializedObject {
    private String id;
    private String app;

    static Pattern compile = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9.]+)");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str =
                "  {\n" +
                "    id=5d93532e77490b00013d8862, \n" +
                "    app=null,\n" +
                "    manufacturer=pearsonEducation, \n" +
                "    bookUid=bookIsbn, \n" +
                "    model=2019,\n" +
                "    firmware=[1.0], \n" +
                "    bookName=devotional, \n" +
                "    accountLinking=mandatory\n" +
                "  }\n";
        String s1 = str.replaceAll("=", ":");
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(s1);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "\"" + matcher.group(1) + "\"");
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

        SerializedObject serializedObject = JSON.parseObject(sb.toString(), SerializedObject.class);
        System.out.println(serializedObject);
    }
}
```